# Vue.js v-slot directive to replace slot directive

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to mimic the default behavior of using the `slot` tag in a parent component. When I use `<template v-slot>` The content doesn't automatically go there. What is the correct way to do this without using the `slot` tag?, as I read that this will be depreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it's the `slot` **attribute** that is [deprecated](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Deprecated-Syntax) (not the [built-in `<slot>` component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#slot)).

Before v2.6, the `slot` attribute was used to specify the name of the slot for the given content, and `slot-scope` received the slot props:

```html
<base-layout>
  <template slot="header" slot-scope="{ subtitle }">
    <h1>Here might be a page title</h1>
    <h2>{{ subtitle }}</h2>
  </template>

  <p>A paragraph for the main content.</p>
  <p>And another one.</p>

  <template slot="footer">
    <p>Here's some contact info</p>
  </template>
</base-layout>
```

From v2.6 forward, those two attributes are combined/replaced with the [`v-slot` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-slot), where the slot name is given as an argument, and any slot props are received in the binding value:

```html
<base-layout>
  <template v-slot:header="{ subtitle }">
    <h1>Here might be a page title</h1>
    <h2>{{ subtitle }}</h2>
  </template>

  <p>A paragraph for the main content.</p>
  <p>And another one.</p>

  <template v-slot:footer>
    <p>Here's some contact info</p>
  </template>
</base-layout>
```